# Clear Activity Android

Tags: android, image, ram

I have a game in which there are several Activities (Shop, game process, menu, registration, etc.) 
How to clean up the Activity (I switched from form of registration to the main menu. 
At the moment of being on the registration screen, 60 MB of the device was wasted,when on menu - flow RAM increased to 120 mb) 
The essence of the question is how to kill the previous Activity ​​so that when going to the next one, 
absolutely nothing comes from "killed Activity" (so that when you call the Activity that we killed it was newly created and did 
not come to the saved state). All recommendations like: finish (), finishaffinity (), noHistory = "true" in the manifest, 
at transition - set in all ImageView emptiness, kill Activities through Intent in the supposedly stack do not lead to anything ..... 
Memory is eaten by pictures. PS pictures are optimized to the maximum: the largest picture weights 20 kb and the smallest 2kb) The memory consumption in Java varies from 15 to 20 mb, but the code itself is 6-8 mb.
Thx your for attention sry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Call to clean up;

```
if(imageBitmap != null) {
     imageBitmap.recycle();
     imageBitmap = null;
}
System.gc();
```